# Do ArrayList or HashSet classes implements Collection interface implicitly?

Tags: java, collections

I read `Lists` and `Sets` are sub-classes of `Collection` then why don't they implement all the methods of `Collection`?

If I try to explicitly write a class that extends one of those interfaces, it gives compile errors requiring me to implement very many methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "Explicitly implementing gives so many method to implement compile time error?" ?

Comment: Interfaces don't implement methods.

Comment: @JonSkeet  public class Enhance implements Collection{ this asks to implement so many methods in eclipse.

Comment: @user3670613: Yes, it would. I still don't understand your actual question though...

Comment: Does it mean that List and Sets are another Collection which has some methods like Collection interface?

Comment: I'd recommend thoroughly reading through the Javadoc for the existing Collection classes before trying to implement your own. What you need more than likely already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard JDK list/set implementations extend [`AbstractList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) and [`AbstractSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html), respectively, which provide a "skeletal implementation" of the `List`/`Set` interfaces. The concrete classes (such as `ArrayList` and `HashSet`) fill in the gaps by implementing any methods that are not covered by these abstract classes (or overriding them as needed). So, just by looking at the `ArrayList` source, for example, you might get the impression that not all methods are implemented, but they are if you also look in `AbstractList` (and `AbstractCollection` -- see below).

Both `AbstractList` and `AbstractSet` extend [`AbstractCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) which implements the `Collection` interface (again providing a "skeletal implementation").

Comment: It means AbstractSet implements collection and give empty implementation of this Collection interface? Am i right?

Comment: @user3670613 `AbstractSet` extends `AbstractCollection` which gives a skeletal implementation of the `Collection` interface. `AbstractSet` adds `equals`/`hashCode` and overrides `removeAll`.

Answer (score 2):

`List` and `Set` are interfaces themselves, they don't implement anything.

`ArrayList` (for example) implements `List` and in order to do that has to also implement `Collection`.